# Who gets an Apparition licence?

Tags: harry-potter

I read a lot of questions lately about Apparition vs. Portkeys. People keep talking about getting a license from the MoM to be able to Apparate legally.

It seems that everyone can learn it since they are teaching it in schools. So how do they decide who can and who can not get a license?

Is it enough to just be able to learn it? Are there other criteria when allowing students the license?

Comment: You get an Apparition licence. And *you* get an Apparition licence! And ***you*** get an Apparition licence! ***EVERYONE*** gets an Apparition licence!

Comment: “They are teaching it in schools”, but the course is not mandatory. To get the licence, you first have to attend. Then, you have to pass the final test.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I think the Harry Potter analog is *you get a broom, you get a broom **Everyone** gets a broom*

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### There's a test

Anybody who wishes to obtain a license to Apparate has to pass a test. From what's mentioned in the books this test appears to be comprised entirely of a practical assessment; the person undertaking the test has to demonstrate that they're able to Apparate both safely and accurately. There's no mention of a written theory component to the Apparition test, as there is for obtaining a driver's license in the UK (and, presumably, other countries).

> “You have not, of course, passed your Apparition Test,” he said.
>
> “No,” said Harry. “I thought you had to be seventeen?”
>
> “You do,” said Dumbledore. “So you will need to hold on to my arm very tightly. My left, if you don’t mind — as you have noticed, my wand arm is a little fragile at the moment.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, Chapter 4, "Horace Slughorn"</sub>

Comment: You might want to mention that the test focuses on safety. Ron fails because of splinching

Comment: _"“He — he just failed,” whispered Hermione, as Ron came slouching into the room looking most morose. “It was really unlucky, a tiny thing, the examiner just spotted that he’d left half an eyebrow behind... How did it go with Slughorn?” "_ HBP, Chapter 22, "After the Burial".

Comment: This answer might benefit from emphasising that the Apparition classes are an *extracurricular activity*, not a core Hogwarts class - it's like a Muggle boarding school arranging for driving instructors to come in and teach outside of normal classes.

Comment: So you think all it takes is to be possible to apparate successfully during a test and that's it?

Comment: @MorZamir There's no suggestion that it involves anything else. The lessons that are described in the book all focus solely on actually Apparating, there's no theoretical knowledge involved. Similarly, all of the mentions of (failed) tests are due to failures to Apparate safely and accurately.

Comment: Note that the UK driving theory test was only introduced in 1996, so it's probable that JK Rowling never needed to take it, and only muggle of Harry's generation onwards would have done.

Comment: @origimbo  Harry was 11 in 1997, and wouldn't be eligible to take the written test until 2003.  Many of the people taking the written test in 1996 would have been in their early-to-mid 20's, so at least a decade older than Harry and some would be two decades older.  (The average age at which people pass their test in the UK varies by region, but the lowest figure is 21.)

Comment: @MartinBonner I'm following the "born July 31st 1980" hypothesis.

Comment: Interestingly, we never see Harry get an apparition test.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Just wait until JKR gets bored, I'm sure she'll write *Harry Potter and the Apparition Test*.